# Google Scripts that converts a sheet to pdf and emails it as an attachment fails after a few successful runs

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have implemented a google script to isolate a specific sheet in a spreadsheet and then convert the sheet to a pdf and email the pdf. The code extracts the email address to send the email to from the sheet itself.

The total number of sheets in the spreadsheet are 9. The code works perfectly until sheet 6/7 (it is inconsistent in where the first fault occurs).

The first 5 or so emails work as intended with the correct sheet being emailed as a pdf that is fully functional.

Emails are sent to all the addresses, but the attached pdfs are unopenable and include the error "Whoops! There was a problem previewing this document" after sheet 6/7.

```
var d = new Date();
var month = new Array();
month[0] = "January";
month[1] = "February";
month[2] = "March";
month[3] = "April";
month[4] = "May";
month[5] = "June";
month[6] = "July";
month[7] = "August";
month[8] = "September";
month[9] = "October";
month[10] = "November";
month[11] = "December";
var n = d.getMonth() +1;
var Year = d.getYear();
if (n == 12) { n = 0; Year += +1;} 
var m = month[n];


var subject = m + " " + Year; 
var body = 'body text.'
var Clients_No = 9;

function sendEmailWithPdfAttach() {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var ssID = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getId();
  var source = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheets = source.getSheets();
  var SpreadsheetName = source.getName();

  SpreadsheetApp.flush();



  for (var no_sent = 0; no_sent < Clients_No; no_sent++){
    var sheetNum = no_sent;//no_sent;    
    var SheetName = sheets[sheetNum].getName();
    var SheetID = sheets[sheetNum].getSheetId();
    var Sheet = source.getSheetByName(SheetName);
    var range = Sheet.getRange(1, 9); //change to 7, 2
    var email = range.getValue();
    var range_account_open = Sheet.getRange(14, 2);
    var Account_open = range_account_open.getValue();

    if (Account_open !== "Account Closed") {
      var url = ss.getUrl();
      url = url.replace(/edit$/,'');
      url = url + 'export?exportFormat=pdf&format=pdf' +
        '&size=A4' + //paper size
        '&portrait=true' + 
        '&fitw=true' +
        '&gridlines=false' + 
        '&fzr=false'; 

      var request = {
        "method": "GET",
        headers: {
        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' +  ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()
      },
        "muteHttpExceptions": true
      };
      var url = Drive.Files.get(ssID)
      .exportLinks['application/pdf'] + "&gid="+SheetID;
      var blob = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url , request).getBlob();
      blob.setName(sheets[sheetNum].getName() + ".pdf"); 
      MailApp.sendEmail(email, subject, body, {attachments:blob});


      //Utilities.sleep(1000);
    }
  }
};
```

What must I change so that all emails sent have pdfs that are openable and functional?

Comment: Clients_No seems undefined:`for (var no_sent = 0; no_sent < Clients_No; no_sent++)`

Comment: I have added in the code for a few of the variables that I initially didn't include in this question.

Answer (score 1):

You may try the suggested actions in this [link](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/drive/1kIqLjtwXlg):

> - Clear your [cookies and cache](https://support.google.com/blogger/answer/32050?hl=en) since beginning of time.
> - Try [Incognito](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95464?hl=en)/[private window](https://www.google.com/url?q=https%3A%2F%2Fsupport.mozilla.org%2Fen-US%2Fkb%2Fprivate-browsing-browse-web-without-saving-info&sa=D&sntz=1&usg=AFQjCNH5YTK-xMxBa1T3e2zbtbk-KMA4Ew).
> - Disable [extensions](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/187443?hl=en)/[add-ons](https://www.google.com/url?q=https%3A%2F%2Fsupport.mozilla.org%2Fen-US%2Fkb%2Fdisable-or-remove-add-ons&sa=D&sntz=1&usg=AFQjCNGd7cm5vfVHX9C4-Ur9LViGVCN_jw)/[plug-ins](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/142064?hl=en).
>
>   - Disable all extensions by doing a browser reset.
>   - Here's a link to the Google Support Center for how to do that: [Chrome Browser Reset](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/3296214?hl=en).
> - Try a different browser to see if it is a browser related issue
> - Make sure you are using the most current OS for your device. Here is a link to [the operating systems Chrome supports](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/2375082?hl=en).
> - Make sure you're using the latest version of Chrome.

Hope this helps!